# Example code for tbl_svysummary function add_ci() produce error message

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm using tbl_svysummary to report weighted means. Additionally I would like to add another column with confidence intervals using add_ci().

If I try, I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("add_ci") :
> no applicable method for 'add_ci' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_svysummary', 'gtsummary')

The same happens if I run the example-code provided by the reference page in the web, that you can see below (https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_ci.html).

Package versions:

- gtsummary 1.5.0,
- survey 4.1-1

Code:

```
# Example 3 ----------------------------------

data(api, package = "survey")
    add_ci_ex3 <-
      survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) %>%
      tbl_svysummary(
        include = c(api00, hsg, stype),
        statistic = hsg ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
      ) %>%
      add_ci(
        method = api00 ~ "svymedian"
      )
```

Basically I just tried around wit the example code an my own data, but I only get the same error message again and again. Searching google and stack overflow doesn't give me any further information on this error. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: support for `tbl_svysummary()` objects in `add_ci()` was just added as an experimental feature in the last release (a couple of weeks ago). Update the pkg and try again?

Comment: Much thanks for the fast reply! This is what I tried first. Both packages (survey and gtsummary) are installed in their latest versions (gtsummary 1.5.0, survey 4.1-1).

Comment: gtsummary is on v1.7.0 right now